# Access Windows 7 Media Streaming

Tags: 10.04, windows-7, rhythmbox, music, plugins

I wish to be able to see and stream music to my Ubuntu 10.04 installation through Rhythmbox. I have enabled media streaming in Windows 7 and I can see Rhythmbox as an allowed device.

I have installed the Coherence plugin for Rhythmbox. I can see my Windows 7 PC under the Shared folder in Rhythmbox, but I do not see any of my music.

Is there a step along the way that I missed or something else that I have to enable?

Comment: Also - I can see Rythmbox from the Windows Media player - but there is no music listed either. I believe the issue is with the plugin, and not network as both are seeing each other but not listing music.

Comment: No need to leave a comment, just edit your question and keep adding information to it!

Comment: Are you seeking to play music files with Rhythmbox from your 7 box?

Comment: I am looking to stream music to my Ubuntu laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed the coherence plugin as well, and at first I had the exact same behaviour as yours. After a little while, my library had shown up (I use a NAS with Twonky installed).

The one thing that comes to my mind, after enabling media sharing in Windows 7, is that you also have to disable "password protect sharing" in the "sharing" configuration pane for DLNA devices to be able to access Windows Media Player library.

Comment: Confirmed DAAP / DLNA streaming does not work with password protected shares. Disable password protected sharing and it *should* work without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install the Firefly Mediaserver. ( http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/ ) It's a streaming server that is open-source and can stream towards Rhythmbox.

I'm not really familiar with the software, so I suggest that you also take a look the following answer: [Music player that can access/catalog music on network drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3944/music-player-that-can-access-catalog-music-on-network-drive/3950#3950).

I hope I could help,
Martijn.

Comment: Firefly looks ok, and I have used it on a self built NAS. The only current issue is that the development has either stopped or slowed down, and the windows port is still in beta.