# Music player that can access/catalog music on network drive

Tags: music

I have all of my music on a network drive hooked up to an Ubuntu server.  I can access the music from my Ubuntu laptop. The problem is that I can't find a program that will use my samba connection to access the music directly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use a streaming server application.

There is  `ampache` (amarok, andriod client, ..), which is a PHP + Mysql webstreaming application.
http://ampache.org/wiki/clients:amarok

and there is the `Firefly Mediaserver` http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/

Firefly has also the support to stream to iTunes and lots of other applications including Rhythmbox.

I would suggest the `Firefly` because it is a little bit easier to setup.

Comment: Very nice!  I went with Firefly because it's a cool name.  Thanks for the advice! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I've been using firefly mediaserver since it was called mt-daapd, and it works great with amarok and other linux music players.

Comment: I use [forked-daapd](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=users/jblache/forked-daapd.git;a=summary) since development on mt-daapd seems to be dead. It is a rewrite and under active development (for now). Although it is not in the Ubuntu repos, it is in the [Debian ones](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/forked-daapd), so it shouldn't be hard to install it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection to the network mount is always there, you could write an `/etc/fstab` entry for it.

[MountWindowsSharesPermanently - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Alternatively, there's NFS but both will struggle and splutter when you're away from the network.

Comment: That's what i did with my Windoze machines (basically mapping a network drive).  I agree it's a pain when away from the network, so I went with Firefly.  thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I add a Bookmark to the Samba share and then add Music Collection via /home//.gvfs//

Only issue is that you need to open the connection to the share first.

Or as Oli put you could go down the route of adding to Fstab.