# Music server + Banshee

Tags: server, music, banshee, ftp

I'm currently trying to figure out some kind of set-up for my music collection. The music collection is located on my "main PC" and I'm using Banshee to play/manage the music.

Since I'm often at a different location where I use my laptop I have a FTP server running on my main PC, use curlftpfs to mount the music in /home/username/Music and sync the Banshee DB/configuration via Dropbox.

The problem at the moment is that Banshee skips songs very often when the connection is a little slower.

I've been looking at some servers like Ampache but they are not really an option since they don't let me use Banshee (which means I have no ability to change metadata or rate songs). 
Syncing the whole collection to my laptop isn't an option either because of its size.

It would be great if you had some ideas how to make my current set-up more reliable or maybe know an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like Banshee doesn't skip any tracks when I add them to the queue and play them from there. I'd say that's good enough :)

Answer (score 4):

Banshee has a DAAP plugin that should be able to see music on your server made available using a DAAP server like Tangerine or mtdaap (both are in the Ubuntu repos).

Comment: See this question, too. http://askubuntu.com/q/3944/19053

Answer (score 0):

There is now an Ampache extension available for Banshee 1.9.0 and above. It's part of the Banshee Community Extensions, and should is available on Ubuntu, either from the official repositories or the [Banshee PPA](https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/banshee-unstable)

It allows you to browse and play your remote music with Ampache from within Banshee, but I'm not sure it has all the features you need : edit metadata, rating, etc.

Comment: I already tried the Ampache extension. It's quite buggy and as you say is very limited in what it does.